# What are higher dimension analogues of loops called?

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology

A path $f:I\to X$ with the same starting and ending point $f(0)=f(1)=x_0\in X$ is called a loop.

What is the higher dimensional analogue of a loop $f: I^n\to X$ called?

Comment: I think these can be described as continuous functions $f : S_n \rightarrow X$, where $S_n$ is the (locally) $n$-dimensional sphere.

Answer (score 1):

We can consider a function $f:[0, 1] \to X$ with $f(0) = f(1)$ as a map $f:S^1 \to X$, where $S^n$ denotes the $n$-sphere (the boundary of the $(n+1)$-ball). Similarly, we can consider a function $f:I^n \to X$ that's constant on the boundary $\partial I^n$ as a map $f:S^n \to X$. The fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ is the set of loops $f:S^1 \to X$ modulo homotopy; the higher groups $\pi_n(X)$ are the sets of loops $f:S^n \to X$ modulo homotopy. (I'm skipping over some details about basepoints, the group action, etc.) To answer your specific question, what you're describing is usually just called a map $f:S^n \to X$, or an embedded (etc.) sphere if $f$ is an embedding (etc.).